# Book about extremely overpopulated world where caring was a liability

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book about an extremely overpopulated world where caring was a liability. It's a love story of how these two people manage to care for each other in that world. It's also about ruthlessness really. I'm trying to find the author and/or the title. There were also outsiders that weren't part of the main system that was featured somehow. I think it was so overpopulated that they had to sleep in shifts.

Comment: You should attempt to add more info and some of the stuff doesn't seem pertinent. Like maybe you should get rid of " ....where caring was a liability" or clear it up a little. Because it seemed a bit confusing.

Comment: This could almost be Harry Harrison's "Make Room, Make Room" (1966) (cf. Soylent Green). There were a few 'haves' and many more 'have nots', but I recall no 'outsiders'.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/identify-story-overpopulation-problem-causes-people-to-live-one-day-a-week

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like Philip Jose Farmer's noted short story "*The Sliced-Crosswise Only-On-Tuesday World*", which he later used as the inspiration for his "*Dayworld*" series. Both are about a future in which everyone sleeps in stasis except one day a week as a solution to overpopulation. The original short story is a thwarted romance between two people who live on different days. I don't remember reading the novel, but according to Wikipedia it features a group of outsiders trying to change the system.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like *The Dosadi Experiment* by Frank Herbert.

> "She'd been taught by loving parents (who'd concealed their love
>   behind exquisite cruelty)".

Comment: Maybe you should tell where the quote came from, is it your quote or is it from the book.

Comment: Based on Wikipedia, it is a cruel world with overpopulation and one where two people find their way together, not sure about the rest. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dosadi_Experiment